# How to create a new variable that contains three calulations that are based on other selected variable' values

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a new variable that contains three calulations that are based on the value of a selected column. 
Here is my data frame example :

```
 dat <- read.table(text = " cats birds    wolfs     snakes
     0        3        9         7
     1        3        8         7
     1        1        2         3
     0        1        2         3
     0        1        2         3
     1        6        1         1
     0        6        1         1
     1        6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

I would like to create a new variable called `dat$full_calc` that will contain the following:
if `wolfs==1` then give the value 1, if `wolfs==2` then give the value 20 , if `wolfs>=8` & `snakes=7` then give the value 88 else give the value 999.
I know how to use `ifelse` command and it works fine but only for two conditions so I'm looking for a way to populate a new variable `dat$full_calc` according to the 3 conditions written above.
the output should be like:

```
       cats    birds    wolfs     snakes full_calc
         0        3        9         7      999
         1        3        8         7      88
         1        1        2         3      20
         0        1        2         3      20
         0        1        2         3      20
         1        6        1         1      1
         0        6        1         1      1
         1        6        1         1      1
```

Any idea is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dat$full_calc <- with(dat, ifelse(wolfs == 1, 1, 
                             ifelse(wolfs == 2, 20,
                                      ifelse(wolfs >= 8 & snakes == 7, 88, 999))))
```

You can nest several numbers of `ifelse` inside each other.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using the `data.table` package, the ability to update a table is pretty transparent and understandable.

```
#Bring in data.table
require(data.table)
setDT(dat)

#Develop full_calc
dat[ , full_calc := 999]
dat[wolfs==1 , full_calc := 1]
dat[wolfs==2 , full_calc := 20]
dat[wolfs>=8 & snakes==7 , full_calc := 88]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try:

```
  indx <- with(dat, cbind(wolfs==1, wolfs==2, wolfs>=8 & snakes==7))
  dat$full_calc <- c(cbind(indx, !rowSums(indx))%*%c(1,20,88,999))
  dat$full_calc   #please check the first value in your expected output 
  #[1] 88 88 20 20 20  1  1  1
```

Suppose, if

```
  dat$snakes[1] <- 6
  indx <- with(dat, cbind(wolfs==1, wolfs==2, wolfs>=8 & snakes==7))
   c(cbind(indx, !rowSums(indx))%*%c(1,20,88,999))
  #[1] 999  88  20  20  20   1   1   1
```